# How do I create a major arc open to the left?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

First a minimal working sample is as following:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Goal: I want a math symbol which is like a circle but misses a left part as in the following picture. Any help is welcome. I hope it has the same line weight and size as `\medcirc` in the `txfonts` package.

[image]

Comment: It looks more like the returned `C` character, doesn't it?

Comment: @AndréC No, it's a math symbol.

Comment: What is this mathematical symbol? What does it mean? Why doesn't it exist in standard packages?

Comment: Just for fun, here is a `picture` version : `\begin{picture}(0,0)(0,-2)\put(0,0){\circle{2}}\textcolor{white}{\linethickness{.3mm}\put(-1.5,0){\line(1,0){1}}}\end{picture}` that requires `xcolor` package.

Comment: Maybe `\mbox{\reflectbox{C}}`?

Comment: Not really a duplicate. Detexify doesn't recognize it. And I'm not finding it in the [comprehensive list](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf). I think you may have to design your own.

Comment: @AndréC It's used personally by Peano in 1889.

Comment: @Davislor `\mbox{\reflectbox{C}}` seems to produce an ugly symbol, haha!

Comment: @Kuttens: By the way, what you've presented is not a minimal example...

Comment: @Kuttens Maybe `\mathrel{\mbox{\reflectbox{\sffamily C}}}` would look a little better? I also have a little solution in TIKZ, but I felt it was redundant with Sandy G’s great answer.

Comment: Do you have a scan of Peano's original use of this symbol in 1889?

Comment: @AndréC yes, very similar to but not the same as the universal quantifier `\forall`.

Comment: @Kuttens Can you add this scan to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an improvement of @Kpym 's answer and the help of `pict2e` and `scalerel` packages, I got a suitable way:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand{\peanoall}{\mathbin{%
\scalerel*{%
\begin{picture}(5,5.5)%
\put(2.5,2.75){\circle{5.5}}
\textcolor{white}{\linethickness{1.25mm}\put(2.5,2.75){\line(-1,0){3}}}
\end{picture}
}{\forall}%
}}
\begin{document}

$\phi\peanoall x,y\cdots\psi$

\end{document}
```

**It could change the size with its location (normal texts or footnotes or scripts).**

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution that uses `\ooalign` to overlay a white rectangle on part of a `\medcirc`.

[image]

`\mathchoice` is used to allow your symbol to appear in script or scriptscript styles. You can edit the `\rule` arguments to adjust height and thickness of the opening in each style.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{txfonts,color}

\newcommand{\arcl}{\mathchoice%
{\mathbin{\ooalign{\hfil$\medcirc$\hfil\cr\textcolor{white}{\rule[.25ex]{.2em}{.65ex}}\hfil\cr}}}
{\mathbin{\ooalign{\hfil$\medcirc$\hfil\cr\textcolor{white}{\rule[.25ex]{.2em}{.65ex}}\hfil\cr}}}
{\mathbin{\ooalign{\hfil$\scriptstyle\medcirc$\hfil\cr\textcolor{white}{\rule[.2ex]{.2em}{.4ex}}\hfil\cr}}}
{\mathbin{\ooalign{\hfil$\scriptscriptstyle\medcirc$\hfil\cr\textcolor{white}{\rule[.15ex]{.2em}{.25ex}}\hfil\cr}}}
}

\begin{document}

$a\medcirc b_{a\medcirc b_{a\medcirc b}}$

$a\arcl b_{a\arcl b_{a\arcl b}}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: I got a more suitable way for which see the posted answer.

Comment: @Kuttens, just watch the spacing on that other solution. You should enclose it in `\mathbin{}` to get the same spacing as `\medcirc`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tipa}
\newcommand{\yoursymbol}{\text{\textopeno}}
\begin{document}
$a^2+\yoursymbol^2+\frac{2}{\yoursymbol}=0$
\end{document}
```

[image]

I get this from [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html). Therefore, your question is possibly a duplicate of [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character).

Comment: OP requested the same size and weight as `\medcirc`. This doesn't really do it.